# Add row when selected from one table to another using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im actually trying to add only a specific row from the table product to the table product_add but the last row is being inserted in the table product_add. What i want is that when I click on the button ADD that specific row is being inserted in the table product_add. I think that the code is not considering the if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) part.

```
  <?php

 include'connect.php';

  $image = isset($_GET['image']) ? $_GET['image'] : "";
  $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
  $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
  $price= isset($_GET['price']) ? $_GET['price'] : "";


    $sql="SELECT * FROM product";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if($result>0){
    ?>
    <form method="POST" id="form" name="form">
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price MUR</th>
</tr>
    <?php

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    extract($row);

 ?>                  

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo ($row['id']); ?></td>
    <td><img src=<?php echo $row['image'] ?>  width='120' height='100'/></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['price']); ?></td>
    <td>

              <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value='ADD'/>

    </td>
    </tr>
            <?php
          }
             ?>
              </table>
                 </form>
               <?php
                  }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
           {

           $insert = "INSERT INTO product_add(id, name, price) VALUES ('$id',  '$name','$price')";
        $insertQuery=mysql_query($insert);
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do not use `extract`, it's the work of the devil and will have you tearing your hair out attempting to find bugs. It's also likely to introduce them if you're using `SELECT *`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add from in each while

like this updated code

```
 <?php
 include'connect.php';

  $image = isset($_REQUEST['image']) ? $_REQUEST['image'] : "";
  $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : "";
  $name = isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : "";
  $price= isset($_REQUEST['price']) ? $_REQUEST['price'] : "";


    $sql="SELECT * FROM product";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if($result>0){
    ?>

        <table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price MUR</th>
        </tr>
   <?php

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


     ?>                  

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ($row['id']); ?></td>
        <td><img src=<?php echo $row['image'] ?>  width='120' height='100'/></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['price']); ?></td>
        <td>
                <form method="POST" action="" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" />
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value='ADD'/>
                </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
            <?php
          }
             ?>
              </table>

               <?php
                  }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {

       $insert = "INSERT INTO product_add(id, name, price) VALUES ('$id',  '$name','$price')";
        $insertQuery=mysql_query($insert);
     }
?>
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: welcome bro but most important think is that you have to check what was doing wrong by you. and how this code will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

basically it a general coding issue
type submit and also name submit is conflicting

first add an attribute in form tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for image or video upload 
then

creat a hidden field named 'something'
like

`<input type="hidden" name="something" />`

and after that use this

`isset($_REQUEST['something']`